# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Edge case with Routing in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a page where user's can "Ask a Question" against a product.

The route is:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Q&A - Ask - by Product",
                "{someProductUri}/questions/ask",
                new { controller = "Questions", action = "Ask" }
            );
```

Which matches:

> /car/questions/ask
>
> /phone/questions/ask

Here's the action:

```
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Ask(string someProductUri)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, i also need to allow the user to select the product on the page itself, e.g with no product pre-chosen in the URI.

Because this controller is in an **area**, this "default URL" will be like this:

> /myarea/questions/ask

So what's happening is, when i get to the action, "someProductUri" is set to "myarea", causing all sorts of grief.

I want to re-use the same action/view for both sets of URL's, but i don't want the route value to be set to "myarea" when it's the default URL.

Hope that makes sense - any ideas?

Do i need a seperate route? Can i add a route constraint so that the "someProductUri" can't be "myarea", so that it doesn't match the route and falls back to the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already have too many routes, so i didn't want to add another just for this edge case.

So i ended up using a route constraint:

```
public class NotEqualToAreaName : IRouteConstraint
{
   public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
   {
      return String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), route.DataTokens["area"].ToString(), true) != 0;
   }    
}
```

Pretty simple, and generic - so i can re-use it anytime i come across this type of edge case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a separate route for the area:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Q&A - Ask - by Product",
            "myarea/questions/ask",
            new { controller = "Questions", action = "Ask" }
        );
```

Comment: yes i could do that, but i was hoping this could be handled by the default area route.

Comment: You could add a constraint to stop your route from matching `myarea`.

Comment: exactly what im trying now... :) a "notEqualtoareaNameconstraint". :)